# Woocommerce update order value after updating cart discount

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to add maximum discount limit on % discount coupons. I've added this code to do so in cart, but payment gateway is still getting the % discount without the maximum limit set by this code. Will I have to update any other value to fix this?
Payment gateway plugging is getting the total using get_total method.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_coupon_options_usage_limit', 'woocommerce_coupon_options_usage_limit', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_coupon_options_usage_limit( $coupon_id, $coupon )
{
     echo '';
 // max discount per coupons
 $max_discount =  get_post_meta( $coupon_id, '_max_discount', true );
 woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
     'id'                => 'max_discount',
     'label'             => __( 'Usage max discount', 'woocommerce' ),
     'placeholder'       => esc_attr( $max_discount, 'woocommerce' ),
     'description'       => __( 'The maximum discount this coupon can give.', 'woocommerce' ),
     'type'              => 'number',
     'desc_tip'          => true,
     'class'             => 'short',
     'custom_attributes' => array(
     'step'  => 1,
     'min'   => 0,
     ),
     'value' => $max_discount ? $max_discount : '',
 ) );
 echo '';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_coupon_options_save', 'woocommerce_coupon_options_save', 10, 2 );
 function woocommerce_coupon_options_save( $coupon_id, $coupon ) {
 update_post_meta( $coupon_id, '_max_discount', wc_format_decimal( $_POST['max_discount'] ) );
}
// filter to change discount if over max coupon amount
function filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount( $discount, $discounting_amount, $cart_item, $single, $instance ) {

$cartCoupons = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();

foreach ($cartCoupons as $key => $appliedCoupon) {
    $coupon = new WC_Coupon($appliedCoupon);
    $couponType = get_post_meta( $coupon->get_id(), 'discount_type', true );
    if ($couponType == 'percent') {
        $maxCouponAmount = get_post_meta( $coupon->get_id(), '_max_discount', true );
        $excludedProducts = explode(",", get_post_meta( $coupon->get_id(), 'exclude_product_ids', true ));
        $cartLines = count(WC()->cart->get_cart());
        $cartLineItems = WC()->cart->get_cart();

        foreach ($cartLineItems as $cartItem){
            $cartProductID[] = $cartItem['product_id'];

            if (!empty($excludedProducts)) {
                $cartLinesWithoutExcluded = array_intersect($cartProductID,$excludedProducts);
            } else {
                $cartLinesWithoutExcluded = $cartProductID;
            }
            $cartLinesWithoutExcluded = count($cartLinesWithoutExcluded);
            $totalCartItems = $cartLines - $cartLinesWithoutExcluded;
            $discount = $maxCouponAmount / $totalCartItems;
        }
    } else {
        $discount = 0.00;
    }

    return $discount;

}

}

// apply the coupon whether it is max discount or a product price adjustment
function apply_max_amount_or_product_price_adjustment(){

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
return;

if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
return;

if ( !is_admin() && !wp_is_json_request() ) {
    global $wp, $woocommerce, $post;
    $cartCoupons = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();
    foreach ($cartCoupons as $key => $appliedCoupon) {
        $coupon = new WC_Coupon($appliedCoupon);
        $maxCouponAmount = get_post_meta( $coupon->get_id(), '_max_discount', true );
        $excludedProducts = explode(",", get_post_meta( $coupon->get_id(), 'exclude_product_ids', true ));
        $couponType = get_post_meta( $coupon->get_id(), 'discount_type', true );
        // $fixedProductPrice = get_post_meta( $coupon->get_id(), '_adjust_price', true );
        $couponAmount = WC()->cart->get_coupon_discount_amount( $appliedCoupon );

        if (!empty($maxCouponAmount) && $couponType == 'percent' && ($couponAmount >= $maxCouponAmount)) {
            $couponAmount = add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 10, 5 );
        }

        if ($couponType == 'fixed_cart') {
            $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
            $couponProducts = explode(',',get_post_meta( $coupon->get_id(), 'product_ids', true ));
            $fixedPricePerProduct = get_post_meta( $coupon->get_id(), '_price_per_product_amt', true );

            foreach( $cart as $cart_item ) {
                if (in_array($cart_item['data']->get_parent_id(), $couponProducts)) {
                    $cart_item['data']->set_price( $fixedPricePerProduct );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'apply_max_amount_or_product_price_adjustment', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_coupon_options_usage_limit', 'woocommerce_coupon_options_usage_limit', 10, 2);
function woocommerce_coupon_options_usage_limit($coupon_id, $coupon)
{
    echo '';
    // max discount per coupons
    $max_discount =  get_post_meta($coupon_id, '_max_discount', true);
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id'                => 'max_discount',
        'label'             => __('Usage max discount', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'       => esc_attr($max_discount, 'woocommerce'),
        'description'       => __('The maximum discount this coupon can give.', 'woocommerce'),
        'type'              => 'number',
        'desc_tip'          => true,
        'class'             => 'short',
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            'step'  => 1,
            'min'   => 0,
        ),
        'value' => $max_discount ? $max_discount : '',
    ));
    echo '';
}
add_action('woocommerce_coupon_options_save', 'woocommerce_coupon_options_save', 10, 2);
function woocommerce_coupon_options_save($coupon_id, $coupon)
{
    update_post_meta($coupon_id, '_max_discount', wc_format_decimal($_POST['max_discount']));
}
// filter to change discount if over max coupon amount
function filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount($discount, $discounting_amount, $cart_item, $single, $instance)
{

    $cartCoupons = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();

    foreach ($cartCoupons as $key => $appliedCoupon) {
        $coupon = new WC_Coupon($appliedCoupon);
        $couponType = get_post_meta($coupon->get_id(), 'discount_type', true);
        if ($couponType == 'percent') {
            $maxCouponAmount = get_post_meta($coupon->get_id(), '_max_discount', true);
            $excludedProducts = explode(",", get_post_meta($coupon->get_id(), 'exclude_product_ids', true));
            $cartLines = count(WC()->cart->get_cart());
            $cartLineItems = WC()->cart->get_cart();

            foreach ($cartLineItems as $cartItem) {
                $cartProductID[] = $cartItem['product_id'];

                if (!empty($excludedProducts)) {
                    $cartLinesWithoutExcluded = array_intersect($cartProductID, $excludedProducts);
                } else {
                    $cartLinesWithoutExcluded = $cartProductID;
                }
                $cartLinesWithoutExcluded = count($cartLinesWithoutExcluded);
                $totalCartItems = $cartLines - $cartLinesWithoutExcluded;

                $new_discount = $maxCouponAmount / $totalCartItems;
                if ($new_discount < $discount) {
                    $discount = $new_discount;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $discount = 0.00;
        }

        return $discount;
    }
}

// apply the coupon whether it is max discount or a product price adjustment
function apply_max_amount_or_product_price_adjustment()
{

    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        return;

    if (did_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals') >= 2)
        return;

    if (!is_admin() && !wp_is_json_request()) {
        global $wp, $woocommerce, $post;
        $cartCoupons = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();
        foreach ($cartCoupons as $key => $appliedCoupon) {
            $coupon = new WC_Coupon($appliedCoupon);
            $maxCouponAmount = get_post_meta($coupon->get_id(), '_max_discount', true);
            $excludedProducts = explode(",", get_post_meta($coupon->get_id(), 'exclude_product_ids', true));
            $couponType = get_post_meta($coupon->get_id(), 'discount_type', true);
            // $fixedProductPrice = get_post_meta( $coupon->get_id(), '_adjust_price', true );
            $couponAmount = WC()->cart->get_coupon_discount_amount($appliedCoupon);

            if (!empty($maxCouponAmount) && $couponType == 'percent' && ($couponAmount >= $maxCouponAmount)) {
                $couponAmount = add_filter('woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 10, 5);
            }

            if ($couponType == 'fixed_cart') {
                $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
                $couponProducts = explode(',', get_post_meta($coupon->get_id(), 'product_ids', true));
                $fixedPricePerProduct = get_post_meta($coupon->get_id(), '_price_per_product_amt', true);

                foreach ($cart as $cart_item) {
                    if (in_array($cart_item['data']->get_parent_id(), $couponProducts)) {
                        $cart_item['data']->set_price($fixedPricePerProduct);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'apply_max_amount_or_product_price_adjustment', 10, 1);
add_filter('woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 10, 5);
```